# Adding or not adding route in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to add a route deppending on a boolean, so if the condtion is meet the route will show and be in the navbar and if not it will not be added.

I have trided to change nav: option depending on a condtion, but I have missed something...

```
{ 
  route: 'aRoute', 
  moduleId: 'modules/something/mySite, 
  nav: cond ? true : false, 
  title: 'mySite', 
  isStatic: false
}
```

Probably I am stupid but I need help on this.. :/

Comment: did u solved the issue? Am meeting the same now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following post should help you do what you want:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2016/05/31/dynamically-add-routes-in-aurelia.aspx

It shows how to add a route dynamically by doing this:

```
this.router.addRoute(
         { route: "secret", name: 'secret', moduleId: "app/secret", 
           title:"Secret", nav:true
         }
    );
```

then refreshing the router with this method call (which you are apparently missing):

```
this.router.refreshNavigation();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but routes are probably built one time and reused, at least those that are part of navigation model (`nav === true`). That would mean that you cannot use dynamic expression for `nav` as it would be processed only once.

If you only need this for the purpose of displaying the route in navbar, then you can create a workaround using [`settings` property](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/4) to mark the route somehow and do condition check when creating navbar.

```js
{ 
  route: 'aRoute', 
  moduleId: 'modules/something/mySite, 
  nav: true, 
  title: 'mySite', 
  settings: { occasionallyVisible: true } // add your own properties here...
}
```

I used `settings.occasionallyVisible` property, but you can add whatever you like.

```html
<li repeat.for="route of router.navigation" 
    if.bind="!route.settings || !route.settings.occasionallyVisible || cond">
  <a href.bind="route.href">${route.title}</a>
</li>
```

Navigation route will be displayed if it doesn't have `settings` property OR `settings.occasionallyVisible` is falsy OR `cond` is `true`. Of course, `cond` would be that condition you need.

Not as elegant, but it should get the work done until you get the better answer :)